# What is the ring defining the intersection of two open affines in a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes, affine-varieties

Suppose we have two affine open subschemes $X=Spec(A)$ and $Y=Spec(B)$ of a separated scheme $Z$ (let's even assume that $Z$ is a $k$-variety). Then we know that the intersection $X\cap Y$ is an affine subscheme.

**My question is:** what is the coordinate ring of $X\cap Y$?

The way to show that the intersection is affine is to notice that $X\cap Y\cong (X\times_k Y)\cap \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal. Since $Z$ is separated, $(X\times_k Y)\cap \Delta$ is a closed subscheme of the affine scheme $X\times_k Y=Spec(A\otimes_k B)$ and hence must be affine.

So now the question becomes: what is the surjective ring map inducing this closed immersion? I want to say it's just $f\colon A\otimes_k B\rightarrow k[A,B], \, a\otimes b\mapsto ab$, where by $k[A,B]$ I just mean the $k$-algebra generated by $A$ and $B$. Then we would just have $X\cap Y=Spec((A\otimes_k B)/I)$, where $I=ker(f)$.

Ravi Vakil uses a similar map in Proposition 10.1.3 to show that the diagonal morphism is a locally closed embedding. But I don't understand what happens when we restrict to $X\times_k Y$.

Comment: Embedding $k[X],k[Y]$ in the function field $k(Z)$, if $Frac(k[X]\cap k[Y])=k(Z)$ then $k[X,Y]$ (the subring generated by $k[X],k[Y]$) is also $k[X]\otimes_{k[X]\cap k[Y]}k[Y]$, but it is unclear to me if this is the whole ring of regular functions on $X\cap Y$.

Comment: I assume by $k[X]$ and $k[Y]$ you really mean $A$ and $B$, right? And what do you mean exactly by the intersection $k[X]\cap k[Y]$? Anyways I was able to find this result on page 39 of Mumford's book and it is exacly what I was hoping for: $X\cap Y=Spec(k[A,B])$. Even if I don't really understand how he ends the proof.

Comment: The intersection of two open subsets $U$ and $V$ in a scheme $Z$ is given by the fiber product $U \times_Z V$. So if $Z  = \operatorname{Spec}A$, $U = \operatorname{Spec}A_f$ and $V = \operatorname{Spec}A_g$, then $U \cap V = \operatorname{Spec} A_f \otimes_A A_g$. This gives at least a local picture of the general case.

Comment: @DKS, yes I agree. And in this case that tensor product is just the product of those two rings: $A_{fg}$. But I wanted to make sure this is also true globally.